# Twilio: Receiving SIP to Region

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to receive SIP calls to the ie1 region using:

```
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/receiving-sip#SIP-URI-region
```

Which states that:

> The region parameter
>
> To specify the geographic region from which Twilio will send SIP-out
>   traffic towards your communication infrastructure, you must include
>   the region parameter in your SIP URI. For example, if the region=ie1
>   parameter is included in your SIP URI, Twilio will send the SIP
>   traffic from the Europe Ireland region:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Response>
     <Dial>
         <Sip>sip:alice@example.com;region=ie1</Sip>
     </Dial> </Response>
```

> us1   North America Virginia
>
> us2   North America Oregon
>
> ie1   Europe Ireland
>
> de1   Europe Frankfurt - (coming soon)
>
> sg1   Asia Pacific Singapore
>
> jp1   Asia Pacific Tokyo
>
> br1   South America São Paulo
>
> au1   Asia Pacific Sydney

However it then goes on to state:

> The region parameter is not supported when calling SIP registered
>   endpoints, the parameter will be ignored if present. SIP-out traffic
>   will always be sent from the Twilio region the SIP endpoint registered
>   with.

Since we can only register SIP enpoints in us1 region, does this mean that this entire section is redundant?  Are we unable to send SIP traffic via specific regions?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[SIP Registration is currently only supported in our US1 datacentre](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/sip-registration#sip-register) so that final line in the documentation about the region is accurate.

The region parameter here is useful if you are sending SIP to your own infrastructure that is hosted nearer to one of these regions, or if you are using [Twilio SIP trunking in a different region](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/getting-started#localized-termination-uris).